# How can I change the color syntax on my VS code theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I download the One Dark Pro theme on my VS code and set it to all my workbenches but it doesn't update the color syntax of the code as shown on its demo pictures when downloading the extension, I saw the extension came with some snippets I tried them on JSON yet nothing changed.

I google the question, I tried copying and pasting the snippets suggested from the extension download onto JSON and that didn't correct the problem, I don't know what configuration I must change to map One Dark Pro color syntax on my machine.

Comment: downloading is not enough you have to select the theme, see the VSC doc pages

Comment: what do you mean by "set it to all my workbenches"?